# Run MIP SDK with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, sdk, microsoft-information-protection

I set up the [MIP SDK sample project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MipSdk-Dotnet-File-ServicePrincipalAuth) following the instructions and everything is working well if i'm using the .NET Framework 4.6.1 provided by the sample; but i'm receiving the followng exception at
`MIP.CreateMipContext(appInfo, "mip_data", LogLevel.Trace, null, null);`
using the same code within .Net Core 3.1 console app (also .Net core webapp btw) :

> Unhandled exception. System.ApplicationException: Unknown exception occurred in MipContext_CreateWithCustomFeatureSettings
> at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Internal.MipContext.CreateWithCustomFeatureSettings(ApplicationInfo appInfo, String path, LogLevel thres
> holdLogLevel, Boolean isOfflineOnly, LoggerDelegate loggerDelegateOverride, TelemetryConfiguration telemetryOverride, FeatureDictionary featur
> eSettingsOverride)
> at Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.CreateMipContext(ApplicationInfo appInfo, String path, LogLevel logLevel, ILoggerDelegate loggerDele
> gateOverride, TelemetryConfiguration telemetryOverride, Dictionary`2 featureSettingsOverride)

Could somebody help me if if the MIP SDK should work with .NET Core and i'm doing something wrong, or it is intended to work with .NET Framework only?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just in case my edit doesn't cause a notification: MIP SDK 1.7.133 and later now support .NET Core on Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows. https://aka.ms/mipsdknuget

Comment: Indeed I was notified only by your comment here - would be a pity to miss this excellent news! :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, we don't fully support .NET Core today. We're planning to add support later this year.

[Edit]: We will be shipping support for .NET Core in the next week or so. It'll work on Windows and Ubuntu.

[Edit2]: MIP SDK 1.7.133 and later now support .NET Core on Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows. https://aka.ms/mipsdknuget

Comment: Do you know if there will be support for .NET Core on RedHat Linux? If so, can you estimate when will it be available?